# Building Intra-Maps Roam from source?

Tags: qgis, tablet, intramaps-roam

I have been using and experimenting with Intra-Maps Roam to collect data in the field for just over a year now.

However, I would like to build from source to take advantage of some of the recent changes that have been added. I tried with instructions from http://roam-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev-guide/Building/ , but have been unsuccessful. Currently using 2.4.2.

Any recommendations for a non-programmer?

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because you have not told potential answerers precisely what you tried and where you are stuck in following that documentation.